# Send Mat frames from android to PC

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm developing an AR application for android. For that I want to send Mat image frames to a back-end PC for processing that image. I successfully captured Mat image frame and converted it to byte[] array as follows.

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    Mat rgb = inputFrame.rgba();

    byte[] arr = ConvertImageToByteArray(rgb.getNativeObjAddr());

    System.out.println(arr.length);
    detectEdges(rgb.getNativeObjAddr());
    return rgb;
}
```

Can anyone suggest me a way to send this Mat rgb frame to back-end and How should I parse back it to image. It's better If you can provide python script for back-end and java code snippet for android.

Comment: This question is too broad to get a good answer, I will flag as such. It is basically asking "how do I serialize an Mat object, and how do I network IO on Android to an arbitrary network service". The only constructive thing I can think of is look into OkHttp and/or Retrofit. Also, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better results using this site.

Comment: Do you want to send the images through data cable or wireless?

Comment: @Zindarod Through wireless (WiFi)

Comment: OpenCV can be built with `Gstreamer`. You can send/receive frames through LAN or WAN using `Gstreamer`.

Comment: @Zindarod Can you give me an example of using Gstreamer in android

Comment: Do you have OpenCV with Gstreamer in your android?

Comment: @Zindarod How can I check it?

Comment: Let me write you a working example. I will comment back when I am done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution,
Instead of using opencv, I used MJPEGHTTPstreamer as in the example [here](https://github.com/foxdog-studios/peepers).